# psql login authentication asking password

Tags: postgresql

I am getting below error for my app using below command

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

After I hit `psql` It asks me a password, not sure which password to provide here.

Please help.

Comment: `sudo` is `superuser do`. So you need a superuser password.

Comment: @Burki: Not true. You need to enter the password of the current session user that has the sudo privilege. The whole point of sudo is to not have the root password in circulation.

Comment: @Patrick you are of course correct. My comment oversimplified the matter.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` is used to execute a command on a Unix/Linux system that is otherwise not available to regular users. It will ask for a password of the current session user. That user needs to have the `sudo` privilege set.

`psql` *may* ask for a password for role `postgres` but in the standard setup (using debian distro) there is no password set for this role. (Which may sound strange because it is the default superuser of the database cluster, but if you are trusted enough to be using `sudo` such that you may impersonate the `postgres` user, then you are assumed also to be responsible enough not to misuse or blow up the database cluster.)